# How to display the results of MongoDB $near query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, location

So I am running a legacy $near search here

```
SoundSpot.find(
{ location : { $near : [ longitude, latitude ], $maxDistance: 100 } }
);
```

But I'm confused on what is actually happening to what I'm finding. To my understanding and research the search will show the documents sorted by location nearest to the given coordinates, but anything that i do to try to see the documents only outputs this large Query. i have no idea what this giant Query means, im not vary familiar with mongo and javascript and i am trying to figure out how exactly i see what the $near did.

```
Query {
_mongooseOptions: {},
mongooseCollection: 
 NativeCollection {
 collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
 opts: 
  { bufferCommands: true,
    capped: false,
    '$wasForceClosed': undefined },
 name: 'soundspots',
 collectionName: 'soundspots',
 conn: 
  NativeConnection {
    base: [Object],
    collections: [Object],
    models: [Object],
    config: [Object],
    replica: false,
    hosts: null,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: null,
    pass: null,
    name: 'user_account',
    options: null,
    otherDbs: [],
    states: [Object],
    _readyState: 1,
    _closeCalled: false,
    _hasOpened: true,
    _listening: false,
    _connectionOptions: [Object],
    '$initialConnection': [Object],
    db: [Object],
    client: [Object] },
 queue: [],
 buffer: false,
 emitter: 
  EventEmitter {
    domain: null,
    _events: {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined } },
model: 
{ [Function: model]
 hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
 base: 
  Mongoose {
    connections: [Object],
    models: [Object],
    modelSchemas: [Object],
    options: [Object],
    _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
    plugins: [Object] },
 modelName: 'soundspot',
 model: [Function: model],
 db: 
  NativeConnection {
    base: [Object],
    collections: [Object],
    models: [Object],
    config: [Object],
    replica: false,
    hosts: null,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: null,
    pass: null,
    name: 'user_account',
    options: null,
    otherDbs: [],
    states: [Object],
    _readyState: 1,
    _closeCalled: false,
    _hasOpened: true,
    _listening: false,
    _connectionOptions: [Object],
    '$initialConnection': [Object],
    db: [Object],
    client: [Object] },
 discriminators: undefined,
 '$appliedMethods': true,
 authenticate: [Function],
 serializeUser: [Function],
 deserializeUser: [Function],
 register: [Function],
 findByUsername: [Function],
 createStrategy: [Function],
 '$appliedHooks': true,
 schema: 
  Schema {
    obj: [Object],
    paths: [Object],
    aliases: {},
    subpaths: {},
    virtuals: [Object],
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: [Object],
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: [Object],
    statics: [Object],
    tree: [Object],
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    plugins: [Object],
    s: [Object],
    _userProvidedOptions: undefined,
    options: [Object],
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
 collection: 
  NativeCollection {
    collection: [Object],
    opts: [Object],
    name: 'soundspots',
    collectionName: 'soundspots',
    conn: [Object],
    queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: [Object] },
 Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
 '$__insertMany': [Function],
 '$init': Promise { [Object], catch: [Function] } },
schema: 
Schema {
 obj: 
  { name: [Function: String],
    key: [Function: String],
    connected: [Object],
    type: [Object],
    location: [Object],
    playlist: [Object] },
 paths: 
  { name: [Object],
    key: [Object],
    'connected.username': [Object],
    type: [Object],
    'location.type': [Object],
    'location.coordinates': [Object],
    'location.longitude': [Object],
    'location.latitude': [Object],
    'playlist.title': [Object],
    'playlist.file': [Object],
    'playlist.votes': [Object],
    _id: [Object],
    username: [Object],
    hash: [Object],
    salt: [Object],
    __v: [Object] },
 aliases: {},
 subpaths: {},
 virtuals: { id: [Object] },
 singleNestedPaths: {},
 nested: { connected: true, location: true, playlist: true },
 inherits: {},
 callQueue: [],
 _indexes: [],
 methods: 
  { setPassword: [Function],
    changePassword: [Function],
    authenticate: [Function] },
 statics: 
  { authenticate: [Function],
    serializeUser: [Function],
    deserializeUser: [Function],
    register: [Function],
    findByUsername: [Function],
    createStrategy: [Function] },
 tree: 
  { name: [Function: String],
    key: [Function: String],
    connected: [Object],
    type: [Object],
    location: [Object],
    playlist: [Object],
    _id: [Object],
    username: [Object],
    hash: [Object],
    salt: [Object],
    __v: [Function: Number],
    id: [Object] },
 query: {},
 childSchemas: [],
 plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
 s: { hooks: [Object] },
 _userProvidedOptions: undefined,
 options: 
  { typeKey: 'type',
    id: true,
    noVirtualId: false,
    _id: true,
    noId: false,
    validateBeforeSave: true,
    read: null,
    shardKey: null,
    autoIndex: null,
    minimize: true,
    discriminatorKey: '__t',
    versionKey: '__v',
    capped: false,
    bufferCommands: true,
    strict: true,
    pluralization: true },
 '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
op: 'find',
options: {},
_conditions: 
{ location: { '$near': [Object], '$maxDistance': 100 },
 _mongooseOption: 'find' },
_fields: undefined,
_update: undefined,
_path: undefined,
_distinct: undefined,
_collection: 
NodeCollection {
 collection: 
  NativeCollection {
    collection: [Object],
    opts: [Object],
    name: 'soundspots',
    collectionName: 'soundspots',
    conn: [Object],
    queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: [Object] },
 collectionName: 'soundspots' },
_traceFunction: undefined }
Query {
 _mongooseOptions: {},
 mongooseCollection: 
 NativeCollection {
 collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
 opts: 
  { bufferCommands: true,
    capped: false,
    '$wasForceClosed': undefined },
 name: 'soundspots',
 collectionName: 'soundspots',
 conn: 
  NativeConnection {
    base: [Object],
    collections: [Object],
    models: [Object],
    config: [Object],
    replica: false,
    hosts: null,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: null,
    pass: null,
    name: 'user_account',
    options: null,
    otherDbs: [],
    states: [Object],
    _readyState: 1,
    _closeCalled: false,
    _hasOpened: true,
    _listening: false,
    _connectionOptions: [Object],
    '$initialConnection': [Object],
    db: [Object],
    client: [Object] },
 queue: [],
 buffer: false,
 emitter: 
  EventEmitter {
    domain: null,
    _events: {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined } },
 model: 
   { [Function: model]
 hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
 base: 
  Mongoose {
    connections: [Object],
    models: [Object],
    modelSchemas: [Object],
    options: [Object],
    _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
    plugins: [Object] },
 modelName: 'soundspot',
 model: [Function: model],
 db: 
  NativeConnection {
    base: [Object],
    collections: [Object],
    models: [Object],
    config: [Object],
    replica: false,
    hosts: null,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: null,
    pass: null,
    name: 'user_account',
    options: null,
    otherDbs: [],
    states: [Object],
    _readyState: 1,
    _closeCalled: false,
    _hasOpened: true,
    _listening: false,
    _connectionOptions: [Object],
    '$initialConnection': [Object],
    db: [Object],
    client: [Object] },
 discriminators: undefined,
 '$appliedMethods': true,
 authenticate: [Function],
 serializeUser: [Function],
 deserializeUser: [Function],
 register: [Function],
 findByUsername: [Function],
 createStrategy: [Function],
 '$appliedHooks': true,
 schema: 
  Schema {
    obj: [Object],
    paths: [Object],
    aliases: {},
    subpaths: {},
    virtuals: [Object],
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: [Object],
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: [Object],
    statics: [Object],
    tree: [Object],
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    plugins: [Object],
    s: [Object],
    _userProvidedOptions: undefined,
    options: [Object],
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
 collection: 
  NativeCollection {
    collection: [Object],
    opts: [Object],
    name: 'soundspots',
    collectionName: 'soundspots',
    conn: [Object],
    queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: [Object] },
 Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
 '$__insertMany': [Function],
 '$init': Promise { [Object], catch: [Function] } },
 schema: 
  Schema {
  obj: 
  { name: [Function: String],
    key: [Function: String],
    connected: [Object],
    type: [Object],
    location: [Object],
    playlist: [Object] },
   paths: 
   { name: [Object],
    key: [Object],
    'connected.username': [Object],
    type: [Object],
    'location.type': [Object],
    'location.coordinates': [Object],
    'location.longitude': [Object],
    'location.latitude': [Object],
    'playlist.title': [Object],
    'playlist.file': [Object],
    'playlist.votes': [Object],
    _id: [Object],
    username: [Object],
    hash: [Object],
    salt: [Object],
    __v: [Object] },
 aliases: {},
 subpaths: {},
 virtuals: { id: [Object] },
 singleNestedPaths: {},
 nested: { connected: true, location: true, playlist: true },
 inherits: {},
 callQueue: [],
 _indexes: [],
 methods: 
  { setPassword: [Function],
    changePassword: [Function],
    authenticate: [Function] },
 statics: 
  { authenticate: [Function],
    serializeUser: [Function],
    deserializeUser: [Function],
    register: [Function],
    findByUsername: [Function],
    createStrategy: [Function] },
 tree: 
  { name: [Function: String],
    key: [Function: String],
    connected: [Object],
    type: [Object],
    location: [Object],
    playlist: [Object],
    _id: [Object],
    username: [Object],
    hash: [Object],
    salt: [Object],
    __v: [Function: Number],
    id: [Object] },
 query: {},
 childSchemas: [],
 plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
 s: { hooks: [Object] },
 _userProvidedOptions: undefined,
 options: 
  { typeKey: 'type',
    id: true,
    noVirtualId: false,
    _id: true,
    noId: false,
    validateBeforeSave: true,
    read: null,
    shardKey: null,
    autoIndex: null,
    minimize: true,
    discriminatorKey: '__t',
    versionKey: '__v',
    capped: false,
    bufferCommands: true,
    strict: true,
    pluralization: true },
 '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
 op: 'find',
 options: {},
 _conditions: 
 { location: { '$near': [Object], '$maxDistance': 100 },
 _mongooseOption: 'find' },
 _fields: undefined,
 _update: undefined,
 _path: undefined,
 _distinct: undefined,
 _collection: 
 NodeCollection {
 collection: 
  NativeCollection {
    collection: [Object],
    opts: [Object],
    name: 'soundspots',
    collectionName: 'soundspots',
    conn: [Object],
    queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: [Object] },
 collectionName: 'soundspots' },
 _traceFunction: undefined }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to apply `$geometry` queries then don't forget to apply index in your schema like this:

```
  location: {
  type: [Number], // <Longitude, Latitude>
  index: {
      type: '2dsphere',
      sparse: false
  },
  required: true,
},
```

Without index(`2dsphere`) you can't use `$geoNear` and `$near` in your `aggregatation`.
For ex:

```
db.places.aggregate([
{
  $geoNear: {
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] }, 
    //coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
     distanceField: "dist.calculated",
     maxDistance: 200, //Meters
     includeLocs: "dist.location",
     num: 5,
     spherical: true
  }
 }
]);
```

In above code near find the nearest place from coordinates you requested.
`distanceField` find the distance in meters and display like this:

```
    "dist" : {
    "calculated" : 42107.6268114667, //Meters
    "location" : [ 
        -74.167457, 
        40.3650877
    ]
}
```

`maxDistance` allows you to find location in range of specified distance in meteres.
`num` is like `$limit` you can restrict how many data will return.

Comment: Thank you so much! but where/how exactly do I display the results? What do i have to do to use and see the results?

Comment: First you have to data to compare it. `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a698d995c4a4fc350915676"),
    "name" : "Huey's Knight Club",
    "address" : "164 Easton Ave, New Brunswick, NJ 08901, USA",
    "radius" : 251,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-02-08T11:43:46.524Z"),
    "location" : [ 
        -74.4542719, 
        40.4997539
    ],
    "duration" : null,
    "infinite" : false,
    "isActive" : false,
    "lastActive" : null
}`
after that you can use `$geoNear` using `aggregation` only. First you need to execute your query in `Robo 3T` to see the result.

Comment: So i have a populated collection that I am comparing, so im a little fuzzy on some things. So all i have to do is run the aggregation? what does the aggregation do with the "sorted" objects, where is the data placed?Do i have to save it to a variable, or does it just automatically query it for me and if so where? The entire concept of querying the data is giving me trouble.

Comment: data already stored in database, you just need to perform `aggregation` on them. You need to see this link =>
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Comment: I read up on the documentation and I think I understand how that should work, and I thought my index was fine, but I'm getting this error  
       MongoError: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no geo 
       indices for geoNear" }

Comment: I thought you passed some wrong parameters in geoNear.  Can you send your query here?

Comment: I'm confident that it is running the aggregate properly exactly the way you detailed it with the schema matching like yours is, but it wants geo coordinates that match with $geonear, I have them indexed as 2dsphere, but for some reason, it doesn't like the way that I have the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're printing the value of the `Query` object, instead of iterating on the result.

You are using Mongoose, but the issue is the same if you're using the native node driver.

For example, if I have one document in my `test` collection:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id": 0, "a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1, "d": 1 }
```

Now if I run this following code, it will have a similar output to what you saw:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, db) => {
    db.db('test').collection('test').find({}, function(err, res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

Note that in the code above, I'm printing the `res` object. The output of the code is:

```
Cursor {
  pool: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler:
   Store {
     s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Server] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: BSON {},
  ns: 'test.test',
  cmd:
   { find: 'test.test',
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     query: {},
     readPreference: ReadPreference { mode: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: undefined },
     slaveOk: true },
  options:
   { readPreference: ReadPreference { mode: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: undefined },
     skip: 0,
     limit: 0,
     raw: undefined,
     hint: null,
     timeout: undefined,
     slaveOk: true,
     db:
.... many more lines ....
```

The difference is that instead of a `Query` object, I see the `Cursor` object.

Now if I iterate on the `res`:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, db) => {
    db.db('test').collection('test').find({}, function(err, res) {
        res.forEach(doc => {console.log(doc)});
    });
});
```

It will print the actual document:

```
{ _id: 0, a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1 }
```

Check out Mongoose's page on the [Query object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) for examples in Mongoose.